# Silent WeasyPrint script run

Tags: python, console, weasyprint

WeasyPrint doesn't support some of the CSS3 features (yet, I hope), and running a Python script throws a long list of ignored entries (eg. box shadows, gradients), then a job summary. Is it possible to run WeasyPrint in silent mode, without any information shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://weasyprint.org/docs/tutorial/?highlight=logging),
you can create a new logger object to override WeasyPrint default behavior. The following code snippet is taken from the documentation page itself.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('weasyprint')
logger.handlers = []  # Remove the default stderr handler
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('/path/to/weasyprint.log'))
```

If you don't want any logging at all, you can remove the last line.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Setting a high logging level with  `logger.setLevel(40)` keeps the log file clear for important errors.

Answer (score 7):

With WeasyPrint, I noticed that most of its log messages in my webserver.error.log file were actually from 'fontTools', which is imported and used by 'weasyprint', eg:

```
head pruned
OS/2 Unicode ranges pruned: [0]
glyf pruned
GDEF pruned
GPOS pruned
GSUB pruned
```

After I 'import weasyprint', which imports 'fontTools', the 'fontTools' logger level is set to INFO:

```
print(logging.getLogger('fontTools'))

<Logger fontTools (INFO)>
```

So if I use:

```
import weasyprint, logging
logging.getLogger('fontTools').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger('weasyprint').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

this stops the INFO messages appearing in my webserver.error.log file.

Optionally could use: '.....setLevel(logging.ERROR)' to also remove the WARNING messages.